# Movie showtime database

Tags: distribution

Some web sites like Google Showtime (no longer active), Fandango and IMDB give movie show times at various theaters.

What is the database that they get this information from? Is this database available to the public?

Comment: I voted to close this because I think it falls under Off Topic: Recommendation. "Recommendation questions asking for movies/TV-shows or resources to locate or watch movie/TV content are off topic. Feel free to ask for people's opinion in chat or take a look at this related question for general guidance on finding what you're looking for."

Comment: This question would be off-topic at SO for essentially being a resource request, or even a third-party support question.

Answer (score 2):

Please note the below answers depend heavily upon your intended usage - depending on if consumption is personal/private or commercial in nature.  In addition, you may have better or additional responses in one of the Stack Exchange programming/development communities.  I recommend you research and understanding the licensing and usage of this data before moving forward with any project.

http://www.ignyte.com/services-web-services.html - This offers an introductory price of $99 per year.  I have not personally used this, so I'm not familiar with additional charges, licensing, or other concerns.

http://www.fandango.com/rss/moviefeed - There is an option to generate an RSS feed based on a zip code, which may be suitable for your needs.  Again, I doubt that this is suitable if your product is commercial.  The RSS feed is published with copyright.

Comment: See sanpaco's response above.